# Not allowed to read a file with correct group permissions? ACL?

Tags: permissions, acl

I just set up a basic [nginx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx) server on my Debian 7.0 server. The config file `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` is barely modified, and begings with:

```
user www-data; # nginx shall run as user `www-data`
```

I then set up a server configuration (file `/etc/nginx/sites-available/filenamehere`), which includes the following directives:

```
root /home/diti/www
access_log /home/diti/logs/access.log;
```

I executed [`setfacl` so that nginx can read all data](https://serverfault.com/a/484819/166176) in /home/ directories, and created
the file `/home/diti/logs/access.log` as a regular user (username is `diti`).

---

```
$ whoami
diti

$ groups diti
diti : diti

$ ls -lh /home/diti/logs/access.log
total 12K
-rw-r-x---+ 1 www-data diti 8.9K Mar 13 16:47 access.log

$ tail /home/diti/logs/access.log
tail: cannot open `access.log' for reading: Permission denied

$ getfacl /home/diti/logs/access.log
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: home/diti/logs/access.log
# owner: www-data
# group: diti
user::rw-
user:www-data:r-x
group::---
mask::r-x
other::---
```

**How comes I am not able to read the log file**, owned by `www-data:diti`? I should be able to, since I (`diti`) belong to group `diti`, and group permissions for the log file are set to `r-x`.

Is it because of [ACL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list)? My filesystem is ext4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getfacl` shows you that the group does not have any permission.

The `ls` output `-rw-r-x---+` is confusing. It does not mean that the group has these permissions but that "someone specific and different from the owner" has it.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that to me! I had a better reading at what ACL actually is, and I came up with the following command: `setfacl -R -m user:www-data:r-x,d:user:www-data:r-x,g:diti:r-x /home/diti/logs`, which grants nginx (`www-data`) to read files and directories in `/home`, **and** grants `diti` the right to read and execute everything in the log directory. I didn't know ACL did **"replace"** the UNIX permissions!

Comment: @Diti ACL doesn't "replace" the classic ugo permissions. Adding a user object does not change the old permissions at all. I guess the file did not have group permissions before you ran `setfacl`.

Comment: You are most likely right – I just noticed my umask is 077 (instead of the "usual" 022, granting read permissions to group). I'll try not to assume anything any more before asking questions on SE! ^^